# Reasons for negative vote

Tags: discussion, voting, comments, down-votes

Currently it is possible to vote negative on a question, but its not important, that you write a reason for this voting. I think is very helpful for writes, she has an questions, why the user voted negative. Its not helpful to get just a negative vote. Maybe the user doesn't understand the question, or the question is not useful for other users, no matter what ...

Perhaps it is possible that it is required to put a comment if the user will vote negative. I think is helpful for users.

Comment: I think this is probably a network-wide function, and not controllable by WPSE? In any case, if I downvote a question (or an answer), I always try to leave the reason as a comment.

Comment: sure, but i think is also usefull for the complete network, other SEs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of topics in SE network that are beaten to death.

Short version - enforcing explanations not going to happen.

Long version - while it seems like a no-brainer to ask for explanation, in practice silent downvotes turn out to be more calm and less dramatic process. There is a lot of effort and tolerance, required from all participating parties, to provide and receive negative feedback.

Without dedication to process it just turns into a mess of insulting comments.